# Copy to system clipboard instead of vim buffer

Tags: linux, vim, clipboard

I would like to set Y and P to copy and paste directly to the system clipboard instead of vim buffer.

I don't want any additional commands. Just the normal ones, but they should copy to and paste from the system clipboard and bypass the vim buffer.

How can I achieve this?

I'm running vim on Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have Vim use the clipboard instead of the default register for yanking, putting, etc., by adding this command to your ~/.vimrc:

```
set clipboard+=unnamed
```

See

```
:help clipboard
:help 'clipboard'
```

Comment: I had to use `set clipboard+=unnamedplus` as per http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard.  The `*` register doesn't copy to my clipboard when I'm running vim from a terminal (which is always).

Comment: For Arch (around 2016-04), I did: `set clipboard=unnamedplus`

Answer (score 23):

You first need to see if vim is compiled with clipboard support, run `vim --version | grep clip` and see if there is a `+` or `-` in front of `clipboard` and `xterm-clipboard`.

If it has clipboard support, copying from and pasting into the `*` or `+` registers should use the system/X11 clipboards, so `"*yy` would copy a line and `"*p` would paste it.

In Ubuntu 10.10 you can install vim-gnome to have clipboard support compiled in.

Comment: I tried both this and the method above but I can't get it to copy to system clipboard. It works fine inside Vim though.

Answer (score 9):

have a try :

```
"+y   and    "+p
```

this works for me, on Ubuntu.

Comment: This one works for me, not the * version. Why are people reporting different things?

Answer (score 6):

The default VIM in Ubuntu is vim-tiny, which is not compiled for system clipboard support. You need to install the full VIM and the Gnome GUI to get clipboard support:

```
sudo at-get install vim-full vim-gnome
```

After you install those two packages you can then use the commands that Akira and wliao mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

yank to the clipboard register:

```
 "*y
```

paste from the clipboard register:

```
 "*p
```

for more information:

```
 :help clipboard
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Works fine in Vim itself but does not seem to affect the system clipboard.

Comment: Oh, it's not working because my version is 7.2 and this seems to be supported in 7.3 only.

Comment: Then why not upgrade?

Comment: It works for me exactly as described, except using +. "+yy.... Why?

Comment: @trusktr: look at the answer of steabert.

Comment: @akira Ahhh, that makes sense. Mine is compiled with a +. :)

Answer (score 0):

On my `Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME Shell)` this enabled clipboard:
`sudo apt-get install vim-gnome`

```
vim --version|grep clipboard
+clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +virtualedit
-ebcdic            +mouseshape        +statusline        +xterm_clipboard
```